# cannot install lein (Leiningen) for Clojure on macOS Catalina (10.15)

Tags: installation, clojure, leiningen

I've been unable to install Leiningen on macOS 10.15; I've followed the install instructions at leiningen.org.

The error I get is

```
gw@MacBook-Pro bin % sh lein
Error: -classpath requires class path specification
```

My classpath is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/gw/usr/bin
```

and the lein install script (from leiningen.org) is in `/Users/gw/usr/bin`

Could the problem be leftover dirs/files from previous installations of lein?

My Macbook Pro is fairly new (< 1 year). Could it be that I don't have some software or package that's needed somewhere?

I've been banging about the Internet and the CLI for several hours and can't find a solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know, but keep in mind it's complaining about a classpath, not a shell path. The message can result from a mistaken Java invocation like this: java -classpath -foo SomeClassName where the -classpath option word seems to be followed directly by another option instead of a colon-separated list or directories and jars. I don't know what went wrong, but, if by any remote chance a relevant directory or jar is actually named starting with a hyphen, you might try renaming it.

Comment: It could be a space in an input, perhaps a folder name. This can cause problems too.

Comment: You provided a PATH, not a CLASSPATH, in the question. Two different things: the former finds executables, the latter finds Java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume in your question above, you meant shell path and not classpath, and your `PATH` environment variable is set to what you showed in your question.  If you installed `lein` as per the instructions, you should not need `sh lein`.  Just `lein` should work.

I presume you've installed the `lein` from `leiningen.org` into `/Users/gw/usr/bin` and that it is executable.

Make sure that the new `lein` is in your path.  See what `which lein` says.  Does it point to the new `lein`? If you had a different version of `lein` installed via `brew`, it might be in `/usr/local/bin` which is first in your `PATH`.

Is `java` installed on your Macbook?  Try `java -version` and see that it returns what you expect.

Make a new empty directory and `cd` to it.
Then run `lein`.  It should show you the usage, if all is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, but it did. I'm posting this because it may be a clue to someone who reads this.

Solution: I deleted the "empty" directory structure that I had created early (i.e., `lein new foo`) and recreated it from scratch (`lein new foo`). Everything worked fine.

My best guess as to why this worked is that I had created the old `foo` directory structure under an old version of `lein` (i.e., before I reinstalled `lein`), and something must have been different after I reinstalled `lein`. Your explanation may vary ;)